# Why is resting membrane potential or a membrane depolarisation localised to the membrane?

Tags: potential, biophysics

Why would a membrane depolarisation be localised to one part of the membrane? If adjacent areas have a more negative potential shouldn't the difference in potential cause charge to flow into the depolarised area, until the potential at all points are equal?

Similarly, why is resting membrane potential restricted to the membrane (and not extend to deeper parts of the cytoplasm)? Why doesn't charge redistribute such that the cytoplasm at all parts of the cell have the same potential?

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is called membrane potential, it's actually the potential difference between inner and outer cell, so in other words *potential difference across the membrane*. Since there is a potential difference of around -70mV in a standard animal cell (interior being the negative), it's normal that a bit more of the negative ions will arrange near the membrane, and vice-versa in extracellular space.

EDIT: I think I understand the thing you are asking. Well first of all, inside the cell there are impermeable anions (these arise from a variety of sources including proteins) that cannot go through the membrane. That helps keeping the negative potential difference a lot. Secondly, the attracted ions may diffuse to one anothers side as you mentioned, but that is compansated with Sodium/Potassium Pump which uses ATP to transfer 3Na+ ions out, and 2 K+ ions into the cells, thus helping the inside of the cell to keep its negative state.

Comment: Yes but if more negative than positive ions are present close to the inside surface of the membrane then wouldn't positive ions flow from further inside due to attraction? In my mind the charges should flow until the entire inside of the cell is at the same potential

Comment: the membrane is not a passive  one, charges can not freely move in the direction of the potential. For that, you haveproteins on the membrane that can open and close  according to some trigger (chemical, potential difference, there are many kinds of pumps, some even work against the potential by making it larger (they require energy to work though)), but the membrane is not passive, that is the important issue, it is acomplex dynamical system

Comment: I think I understand the thing you are asking. Well first of all, inside the cell there are impermeable anions (these arise from a variety of sources including proteins) that cannot go through the membrane.  That helps keeping the negative potential difference a lot. Secondly, the attracted ions may diffuse to one anothers side as you mentioned, but that is compansated with  Sodium/Potassium Pump which uses ATP to transfer 3Na+ ions out, and 2 K+ ions into the cells, thus helping the inside of the cell to keep its negative state,

Comment: uhh.. my question is not about how the resting membrane potential is established, I understand that..

Comment: It's about why the membrane potential is restricted to the region close to the membrane

Answer (score 0):

The resting membrane potential is restricted to the immediate vicinity of the plasma membrane is because it is not a true potential in the strictest sense between the cytosol and the ECF, but is rather as a result of potassium ions continuously leaking out of the cell at the plasma membrane, leaving behind a local negative charge on the cytosol side of the membrane which does not significantly dissipate into the cytosol since the cytosol is close to electrically neutral (the negatively charged proteins cancel the positive potassium ions)